# AngularJS filter multiple specific objects

Tags: angularjs

I trying to make a filter with AngularJS that filters specific data parts of a scope, for example:

```
$scope.opdrachten = [
    {"organisation":"Organisation1","number":"7ZDG54","city":"Amsterdam"},
    {"organisation":"Organisation2","number":"9D4F3G","city":"New York"},
    {"organisation":"Organisation3","number":"1AS2S3","city":"Paris"},
    {"organisation":"Organisation4","number":"4A5T7D","city":"Oslo"},
];
```

This is what i have in my scope to filter, but i only want to filter organisation and number without AngularJS filtering city. I have already managed that Angular only filters organisation but i can't find any documentation that shows me how i can filter multiple sections of the scope.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwrLc/81/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello what do you think of this solution : 
    [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUv3z/)

```
<div style="background:#eee;" ng-repeat="emp in opdrachten | filter:query">

$scope.query = function (emp) {
return emp.organisation.indexOf($scope.queryFilter)!=-1 ||  emp.number.indexOf($scope.queryFilter)!=-1 ;
```

}